# Достаточно ли обнулить первый элемент массива?

Tags: c

```
char ups[] = "ups, ups, ups";

ups[0] = '\0';
```

Чтобы считать строку пустой? Или надо очищать все?

```
memset(ups, 0, sizeof(ups));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После обнуления этот указатель будет указывать на строку нулевой длины. Т.е., да, достаточно.

Но нужно понимать, что память не освободится.

Answer (score 0):

С другой стороны, если у нас сделан массив строчек как char [], то удобно строчки разделять символом '0', а в качестве флага конца массива использовать '00'. Поэтому все зависит от реализации. К тому же, если мы пишем этот массив в файл, то там нужно самому четко определять тот объем, который будет писаться. По крайней мере с функциями типа fwrite.

Для стандартных же строковых функций - да, обнуления первого элемента будет достаточно.